# How can I limit selected options in select element when using shift key

Tags: javascript, jquery, range, shift, multiple-select

**HTML**

```
<select id="my-select" multiple="multiple" size="8" style="width:200px">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#my-select option').on('click',function(){
    var count = $('#my-select').find('option:selected').length;
    $('#dg').html(count);
        if(count>10){
            $(this).attr('selected',false); 
    alert('limit 10');
         }
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LxNMm/

When you click on the options, calculate count of selected options and limit it to 10, but if you click on the options with pressing shift key and select a range, selection could be greater than 10. How can a detect count of selected options when select a range with pressing shift key

Answer (score 1):

You can try updating the values this way:

```
 $('#my-select').on('change', function () {
    var count = $(this).find('option:selected').length;
    $('#dg').html(count);
    if (count > 10) {
       $('option:gt(9)', this).attr('selected', false);
       count = $(this).find('option:selected').length;
       $('#dg').html(count);
       alert('error');
    }
});
```

[Your updated demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LxNMm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `click` event of the `<option />`s but the `change` event of the `<select />`

```
$('#my-select').on('change', function () {
    var count = $(this).find('option:selected').length;
    $('#dg').html(count);
    if (count > 10) {
        $(this).find("option").prop('selected', false);
        alert('error');
    }
})
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XsTK9/1/)

Comment: Thank you @Andreas, it works for shift key, but I don't want to do exactly that. I want to clear latest selection if selection count greater than 10 when pressing Ctrl key for one by one selection. But it cleans the whole selection if count gt 10.